# Connect gmail accounts to google pub/sub for monitoring new emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to set up `google cloud pub/sub service` in my `rails` application to receive a push notification on `callback url` through a gmail service account whenever a new email comes in gmail inbox.

I have successfully set up `ruby subscriber client` that receives the messages from pre-defined topic in a `callback url`. I have tested it by publishing test message from google console.

Now my problem is that I cant figure out how to connect gmail account/s to the `topic` so that they automatically start publishing messages to that topic. Can someone please guide me as this is my first time setting up `Pub/sub service`.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I were able to find the working solution and posting answer for others. After connecting to my `subscription` and successfully receiving test message to a `callback` url, this is how I connected gmail account for receiving new email notifications:

Step 1: Create `google oauth authoriser` with following `scope`

```
scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify']
```

Step 2: Create a `watch request` for the authorised user

```
watch_request = Google::Apis::GmailV1::WatchRequest.new(
  topic_name: TOPIC_NAME,
  label_ids: ['UNREAD', "INBOX"],
  label_filter_behavior: 'INCLUDE'
)

watch_response = gmail_service.watch_user(email, watch_request)
```

Analyse the response for the successful watch request and then you are good to go.